# How to bypass (deprecated) reCAPTCHA V1?

Tags: php, authentication, web-deployment, recaptcha

Google has shut down reCAPTCHA v1 but the site I'm using  has yet to update to reCAPTCHA v2. I notified the developer but it may take some time to be fixed.
Is there any way to bypass it?

reCAPTCHA v1 Error Message:

[image]

Comment: no probably not.

Comment: Yup, upgrade it. They've been warning devs for ages now, and when it's deprecated it is of course deprecated *for good*.

Comment: It's not my site. As I stated, I reached out to the developer, a Government Agency. I have no control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After various attempts, I entered "reCAPTCHA V1 IS SHUTDOWN" and it worked!

Comment: I believe you can enter any random text.

Comment: I did try "reCAPTCHA V1 IS SHUTDOWN" as shown on the image and any random two word combination. It does not work. Any info about this?

Comment: I do also having the same problem. looking forward for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

please upgrade to reCAPTCHA v2 immediately. We no longer support reCAPTCHA v1. Any calls to the v1 API will not work after March 31, 2018. Please register a new key and upgrade to v2.